# Mock custom implementation of CodeAccessSecurityAttribute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a custom implementation of [CodeAccessSecurityAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.permissions.codeaccesssecurityattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) that is connecting external sources to do a validation.

```
[Serializable]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class IsAuthorizedAttribute : CodeAccessSecurityAttribute
{
    private static readonly PrincipalPermission Allowed = new PrincipalPermission(PermissionState.None);
    private static readonly PrincipalPermission NotAllowed = new PrincipalPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);

    public string EntityObject { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public char Expected { get; set; }

    public IsAuthorizedAttribute(SecurityAction action)
            : base(action)
    {
        //setup
    }

    public override IPermission CreatePermission()
    {
        return IsAuthorised(EntityObject, Field, Expected, ServicesConfiguration) ? Allowed : NotAllowed;
    }

    private static bool IsAuthorised(string entityObject, string field, char expected, ServicesConfiguration servicesConfiguration)
    {
        bool? response = null;
        //check external stuff
        return response ?? false;
    }
}
```

I have decorated my methods with this attribute:

```
[IsAuthorized(SecurityAction.Demand, EntityObject = Fields.UserManagement, Field = Fields.AllowDisplay, Expected = '1')]
public List<Group> GetUserGroups()
{
    var response = new List<Group>();

    //Get the groups from the database
    var groups = groupManager.FindAll();

    //Map them to the output group type
    response = groups.Select(x => new Group()
    {
        ID = x.ID,
        Name = x.Name,
        Alias = x.Alias,
        Description = x.Description
    }).ToList();

    return response;
}
```

I now want to unit test this method, but the attribute is fired. I have tried some things to mock the attribute, but without success.

I'm using Moq and [Smocks](https://github.com/vanderkleij/Smocks).

This is my unit test without a mocked instance of the attribute:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetUserGroups_UserGroupsFound_UserGroupsReturned()
{
    Smock.Run(context =>
    {
        //Arrange
        Setup();

        m_Container
                    .RegisterMock<IGroupManager>()
                    .Setup(x => x.FindAllFromCache())
                    .Returns(new List<Concept.Security.MasterData.Domain.Group>()
                    {
                        new Concept.Security.MasterData.Domain.Group()
                        {
                            Name = "MyUserGroup",
                            Alias = "My User Group",
                            Description = "My user group description",
                            System = false,
                            Authorizations = "000001111100000000"
                        },
                        new Concept.Security.MasterData.Domain.Group()
                        {
                            Name = "MySecondUserGroup",
                            Alias = "My Second User Group",
                            Description = "My second user group description",
                            System = false,
                            Authorizations = "000000000000000000"
                        }
                    });

        var identityService = new UserManagementService(m_Container, m_UserAuthorizationManager.Object, m_IdentityService.Object);

        //** begin add mocked attribute **//
        //** end add mocked attribute **//

        //Act
        var response = identityService.GetUserGroups();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(2, response.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, response.Where(x => x.Alias == "MyUserGroup").Count());
        Assert.AreEqual(1, response.Where(x => x.Alias == "MySecondUserGroup").Count());
        Assert.AreEqual(2, response.Where(x => x.Authorizations == null).Count());
    });
}
```

Running this results in an exception because the attribute tries to connect the external services and they aren't (and can't be) setup to receive requests.

So, I try to add a mocked attribute:

```
//** begin add mocked attribute **//
var identityService = new UserManagementService(m_Container, m_UserAuthorizationManager.Object, m_IdentityService.Object);

var IsAuthorizedAttribute = new Mock<IsAuthorizedAttribute>(MockBehavior.Strict, new object[] { SecurityAction.Demand });
IsAuthorizedAttribute.Setup(x => x.CreatePermission()).Returns(new PrincipalPermission(PermissionState.None));
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(identityService, IsAuthorizedAttribute.Object);
//** end add mocked attribute **//
```

But this one is calling the constructor of the attribute where I set up the external source. When I put this constructor in a try/catch and silently disposing the exception, I have an error on *IsAuthorizedAttribute.Object* object can't be found.

What are other options to not fire the attribute?

Comment: You are going to have to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: On another note, this is a clear indicator that the attribute is trying to do too much *(ie Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) violation)*. Defeating the intended purpose of attributes as  they relate to .net practices.

Comment: @CyclingFreak Can you elaborate more about "... When I put this constructor in a try/catch and silently disposing the exception, I have an error on IsAuthorizedAttribute.Object object can't be found.", What exception do you face? In what method do you face it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors should not access externals; otherwise it will be difficult to bypass for testing, as you know.

A simple way is to make static `bool` field to bypass. This does not look so good but maybe enough.

```
public class IsAuthorizedAttribute : CodeAccessSecurityAttribute
{
    // set true in the test initialization
    private static bool s_byPass;

    public IsAuthorizedAttribute(SecurityAction action) : base(action)
    {
        if (!s_byPass)
        {
           // setup
        }
    }

    private static bool IsAuthorised(string entityObject, string field, char expected, ServicesConfiguration servicesConfiguration)
    {
        if (s_byPass) { return true; }

        //check external stuff
    }
}
```

Another better approach is to extract the external dependency to another class so that you can mock it. Mocking external dependencies is a typical pattern of a unit test.

```
public class IsAuthorizedAttribute : CodeAccessSecurityAttribute
{
    // set mock here in the test initialization.
    // I assume external accessor can be a static field.
    private static ExternalAccessor m_accessor = new ExternalAccessor();

    private static bool IsAuthorised(string entityObject, string field, char expected, ServicesConfiguration servicesConfiguration)
    {
        return m_accessor.Check();
    }
}

public class ExternalAccessor
{
    private bool m_initialized;

    private void Setup()
    {
        // setup
        m_initialized = true;
    }

    public virtual bool Check()
    {
        // You can call setup anytime but the constructor.
        if (!m_initialized) { Setup(); }

        // check external stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used the second method. I should have thought of it myself to use an external class that could be mocked.